# What is the formula to calculate $R_0$ (basic reproduction number)?

Tags: virology, theoretical-biology, infectious-diseases

What is the mathematical formula for $R_0$ and what does each variable represent?

I have tried searching this to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

> $$R_0 ∝ \left(\frac{\text{infection}}{\text{contact}}\right) · \left(\frac{\text{contact}}{\text{time}}\right) · \left(\frac{\text{time}}{\text{infection}}\right)$$
>
> More specifically:
>
> $$R_0 = τ · \bar{c} · d \quad \quad (1)$$
>
> where $τ$ is the transmissibility (i.e., probability of infection given contact between a susceptible and infected individual), $\bar{c}$ is the average rate of contact between susceptible and infected individuals, and $d$ is the duration of infectiousness.

- [Notes On $R_0$](https://web.stanford.edu/~jhj1/teachingdocs/Jones-on-R0.pdf) (2007)

---

Further reading:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_reproduction_number
- [Complexity of the Basic Reproduction Number (R<sub>0</sub>)](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/25/1/17-1901_article), emerging Infectious Diseases (2019)
- [Theory versus Data: How to Calculate R<sub>0</sub>?](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0000282), PLoS One (2007)
- [The R0 package: a toolbox to estimate reproduction numbers for epidemic outbreaks](https://bmcmedinformdecismak.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1472-6947-12-147), BMC Medical Informatics and Decision Making (2012)